# Permutations COUNT IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How can I get count of Permutations in simple query without generating all Permutations?

like combination function in excel
Permutation(n,r)=result

like `ermutation(6,2)=result,Permutation(12,3)=result,Permutation(20,4)=result`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this UDF will help

**For example**

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Permutation](12,3)
```

**Returns**

```
1320
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Stat-Permutation](@Objects int,@Sets int)
Returns Float
As
Begin
    Declare @P float,@C float
    Select @P=@Objects,@C=@Objects
    While @C>@Objects-@Sets+1 
        Begin
            Set @P = @P * (@C-1)
            Set @C = @C - 1
        End
    Return @P
End
-- Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Permutation](15,4)   -- 32,760
-- Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Permutation](10,10)  -- 3,628,800
-- Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Permutation](25,25)  -- 1.5511210043331E+25
```

> **Edit - To Validate Results**

http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/combinations-permutations.aspx